# Proving $f(x) \ge 1+x$ if $f'$ increasing and $f(0)=f'(0)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f'$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(0)=f'(0)=1.$ Prove that $f(x) \ge 1+x $ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I'm not really sure where to start with this one. It makes intuitive sense, but I don't know how to go about proving it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(x) = f(x) - 1 - x$ satisfies 
$$
 g'(x) = f'(x) - 1 = f'(x) - f'(0) \begin{cases}
 < 0 \text{ for } x < 0 \, ,\\
 > 0 \text{ for } x > 0 \, .
\end{cases}
$$
So $g$ is (strictly) decreasing on $(-\infty, 0]$ and (strictly) increasing on $[0, \infty)$.

Therefore $g(x) \ge g(0) = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

(*Remark:* What this essentially means is: If $f'$ is increasing then $f$ is *convex,* so that the graph of $f$ lies above its tangent line at $x=0$.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x > 0$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $0 < c < x$ such that 
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(c)$$

But $c > 0$ and $f'$ is increasing, so $f'(c) > f'(0)=1$. You get 
$$f'(x) > x +1$$

Similarly, if $x < 0$, the mean value theorem gives you that there exists $x < c < 0$ such that 
$$\frac{f(0)-f(x)}{0-x} = f'(c)$$

But $c < 0$ and $f'$ is increasing, so $f'(c) < f'(0)=1$. You get again
$$f'(x) > x +1$$

The case where $x=0$ is immediate.